# Meaning of operators that are neither observables nor transformations

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, quantum-interpretations

In single particle QM, operators mainly had two roles: They either were hermitian, so any state the system was in could be expanded in eigenstates of said operator, with an eigenvalue assigned to each eigenstate. The interpretation of time-evolution (either of the state or of the operator, in the Heisenberg-picture) is clear: The probability amplitudes for different values change in time. So a set of hermitian operators are linked to reality in so far that they encode information on what values we can measure with a certain probability, in each individual moment in time.

The other option is that the operator is unitary, and describes transformations (dependencies) between different states, that we can interpret for example as rotations of our system. In that case time evolution of such an operator (for example in Heisenberg picture) doesn't tell us something about a particular instance of the system in observation, but instead about a realisation of such a transformation would change over time. Most times, don't care about time evolution of such an operator.

With QFT, we now have field operators being the central operators of interest, and they serve as building blocks to any observable that we might think of. However, they are not hermitean, and even if they were, the nature of qft makes it hard to have a corresponding set of eigenvalues / orthogonal complete eigenvectors. That means, when we talk about time evolution of the field operators, we can't link them to some fancy shift of the probability outcomes of measurements in the same naive way, although they are basically the dynamic entity of the QFT.

Because of this I'm trying to find a new way to picture their time evolution, but up until now, I can't think of any physical interpretation, besides "fancy bookkeeping device for the calculation of expectation values". What can be said here?